# Asset Pipeline/Framework for PHP to build assets based on file content

Tags: php, assets, assetic, fingerprinting

Is there any asset pipeline/framework for PHP that builds assets based on the file's content instead of its modification time?

e.g. index.js will be built into index-[hash].js, when that hash is based on the file content.

I've found that CHH/Pipe (https://github.com/CHH/pipe) does that but lacks filters, docs & community compared with Assetic, which build files by their modification time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, it's possible thanks to everzet and his AsseticPipeline class suite and will probably be brought in next Assetic major version.

If you like Symfony2, you can test it by cloning the previous KnpRadBundle version by [cloning this repo](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/tree/v1.0).
If you want more information about how to implement it in your project : [read this discussion](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/issues/71?source=c)

Good luck.
Hope it helps !